# Compare price like 30 Lac <3 Cr

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am adding a filter in one of my project like:

```
<select id="drpPrice" name="Price">
  <option value="">Price</option>
  <option value="1">< 30 Lacs </option>
  <option value="2">< 50 Lacs</option>
  <option value="3">< 70 Lacs</option>
  <option value="4">< 90 Lacs</option>
  <option value="5">< 1.5 Cr</option>
  <option value="6">< 3 Cr</option>
</select>
```

and I have Price in divs like 23 Lacs, 2.3 Cr,52.5 Lac

How I can compare the values if dropdown changes. I want to display divs that matched with results only.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you have duplicate values?

Comment: This kind of question should really explain what are "Lac" and "Cr".

Comment: @JamesZ , Its a monetary short terms for Lakhs and Crores.

Comment: I know, and I know what they mean, but not everyone knows Indian words.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the DOM like this

```
<select id="drpPrice" name="Price" onchange="compare()">
  <option value="">Price</option>
  <option value="3000000">< 30 Lacs </option>
  <option value="5000000">< 50 Lacs</option>
  <option value="7000000">< 70 Lacs</option>
  <option value="9000000">< 90 Lacs</option>
  <option value="15000000">< 1.5 Cr</option>
  <option value="30000000">< 3 Cr</option>
</select>
```

Then you can create a simple javascript function to compare the values.

```
<script>
function compare(){
     var value = document.getElementById("dprPrice").value;
     //Now compare the value with anything you want to compare with
}
</script>
```